# How to make docker only use a eth1 interface to communicate with other hosts?

Tags: docker

I'm using the Digital Ocean. The interface "eth1" is private and the "eth0" is public. How to make the bridge created by docker `docker0` use only the private interface eth1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bridge created by docker isn't attached to any physical interface.  External access is mediated by layer 3 forwarding and NAT rules in your iptables `nat` table.

This means that you can control which interface is used by Docker containers by manipulating your routing table and or firewall rules.  For example, to prevent your containers from forwarding traffic out `eth0`:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o eth0 -j DROP
```

This would drop any traffic from containers that would go out `eth0`.

Of course, if (a) your container is trying to access an external host and (b) the only route to that host is via your default gateway, which is probably out `eth0`, then your container is now out of luck.

Comment: I had to insert rather than append the rule: `iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0 -o eth0 -j DROP`